# how can i upload a source folder to a generation system?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a web application project. It's like a generation system that takes a source folder with many files, analyse them and then generate another folder that maintains the same business logic but with a different code and different framework.

My problem is that the generation system should have an application source folder as an input to start the generation process and I don't know 
how to do that. Do I need to upload the whole source application folder to the server or the input would be just a path of my folder in local?

Any ideas, suggestions  would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Giving the server network access to your local seems clunky unless the input/output is very large. If the files are larger you could make an executable that is run locally and calls out to endpoints when needed. For a web application you could have it accept a zip file as an upload. The server can unzip the folder and generate the new folder, zip up the new folder and offer it to the user as a download.

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: thank you for your reply
you are right the source folder is a little bit large, about 120 Mb, i'm still working on the core of the system but  i'm confused about making it a web app or just a desktop app !! i know that as a desktop app would be much easier but i prefer a web app 
you said that i can have it accept a zip file as an upload  than the server can unzip the folder, could you be more explicit bout it !! ,cuz im still working in local ,(tomcat ,spring ,hibernate ,jsf ) , and is there any possible way to solve this problem with web-services ?